# create_user() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) Django Social Auth use Costom User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication, django-custom-user

i want to make login social auth and i use userprofile to login, but i getting error. This is error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /complete/facebook/
Exception Value: create_user() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

this is my admin.py code

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('username', 'email','password')

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]

    try:
        UserProfile._default_manager.get(username=username)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return username
    raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

this is model.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

    user = self.model(
        username = username,
        email    = self.normalize_email(email),
    )
    user.is_active  = True
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

# def create_user(self, username, email):
#   return self.model._default_manager._create_user(username=username)

def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
    user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user 

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

alphanumeric    = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', unique=True, max_length=244)
username        = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
first_name      = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
last_name       = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
date_of_birth   = models.DateField(null=True);
date_joined     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)

profile_image   = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile")

objects         = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

def get_full_name(self):
    fullname = self.first_name+" "+self.last_name
    return self.fullname

# def is_authenticated(self):
#   return True

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.username

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

i already put password in fields class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta) but its still same error.

can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this might help

```
def create_user(self,email, password=None,**kwargs):
```

OR check these links might help you what you want.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462929/django-error-create-user-takes-at-least-2-arguments-3-given)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294407/how-to-create-a-user-with-just-first-name-last-name-and-emai-and-not-with-the)

Answer (score 0):

create_user() has only 3 arguments, and when you try to give more or less arguments, then such error occurs. For example, to avoid this error try like this--
definition of create_user()--

```
def create_user(self, email, **kwargs):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Must have an email address')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, name=kwargs['name'])
    user.set_password(kwargs['password'])
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

calling the create_user()--

```
user = self.create_user(email, name=name, password=password)
```